# How does one create a .NET Expression with NodeType of ExpressionType.Index?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees, clr4.0

I'm writing code that evaluates .NET `Expression` trees.  I'm trying to create a C# 4 test to exercise my handling of an `ExpressionType.Index`, but I can't figure out how to create that type of expression through a `LambdaExpression`.  No matter what I try, the expression comes out as an `ExpressionType.Call` or `ExpressionType.ArrayIndex`.  For example:

```
IList<int> myList = new ObservableCollection<int> { 3, 56, 8 };
Expression<Func<int>> myExpression = () => myList[3]; 
// myExpression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call

myList = new int[] { 3, 56, 8 };
myExpression = () => myList[3]; 
// myExpression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call

int[] myArray = new int[] { 3, 56, 8 };
myExpression = () => myArray[3]; 
// myExpression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.ArrayIndex

List<int> myNonInterfaceList = new List<int> { 3, 7, 4, 2 };
myExpression = () => myNonInterfaceList[3]; 
// myExpression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call
```

What is an `IndexExpression`, and can one be created through an inline `LambdaExpression` in C# 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `IndexExpression` is exactly what you expect (i.e., array access or indexer property). It's one of the many new expression types that was ported over from the DLR. The C# 4.0 compiler, however, uses the same expression types as its previous version, so it won't use `IndexExpression` anywhere. Other languages may do so if their designers wish it.

To create an `IndexExpression` programmatically, use the static `ArrayAccess()`,`MakeIndex()`, or `Property()` methods on the `Expression` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Where did you find that information?  If there are some good articles out there that can shed some additional light on expression trees, I'd like to read those articles.